# How do I activate Prowler mode?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

How do I activate prowler mode in "Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate"? I could not find prowler mode anywhere in the game, but I heard that you could do it.

Answer (score 3):

Prowler mode isn't available in Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate.  It's a new mode that was introduced in Monster Hunter Generations and so far is only available in Monster Hunter Generations.